# NuxtJs 2.0 - How can I avoid bundling libraries that aren't needed on the client side

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm facing a problem right now in Nuxt, what I'm trying to do is i'm generating a static site from values that I retrieve in my API.

Of course, I need some libraries in order to:

- Retrieve the pages (Axios)
- Change from markdown to html (Marked)
- Maybe others later..

These things should be done during the generation, meaning on the server side. If I do `npm run generate`, I shouldn't see those libraries bundled inside my script files. Nevertheless I do see them when I run `npm build --analyze`, so I'm 99% sure they are inside npm run generate also.

I tried different solutions, using those librairies in asyncData, only when process.server, *importing* and *requiring* but whatever i'm doing, i'm seeing the library afterwhile in `vendors.pages/index.js` when I *analyze*

Do you have any solution on that ? Maybe using payload on generate would avoid it, but I doubt :/ and payload is more for slug pages as far as I understand.. I'm generating my index content with this API content so it's a bit tricky..

Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have a solution, please let me know if this would be the right way or if you have any other suggestion!

OK so for anyone who is struggling with this, one solution, brought on the Nuxt discord, would be to use [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) in nuxt.config.js

You should then change nuxt.config.js that way:

```
build: {
  extend (config, ctx) {
    if (ctx.isClient) {
      config.externals = {
      // removing axios from the bundled library
      axios: 'axios'
    }
  }
}
```

Doing this is actually removing axios from he bundle on the client side.Not sure if it's the best solution but looks like it works!

Answer (score 0):

The externals workaround excludes axios from **all** clientside scripts, but maybe later a page needs axios.

I suggest using webpack's code splitting:

```
if (process.server) {
  const { default: axios } = await import('axios');
  // axios stuff
}
```

or if you're having trouble with async-await:

```
import('axios').then(function (axiosModule) {
  const axios = axiosModule.default; 
  // axios stuff
});
```

That will create a separate bundle for axios that will only be loaded when needed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks you for your feedback. 
The problem that I have is that I tried using the marked library.
<br/>
So let's take this example:
`import('marked').then(marked => { console.log(marked(result.data)  });`

This will throw an error, saying that _marked is not a function_. 
I can't find a solution using dynamic imports that would work unfortunately

Comment: I forgot that with import(), you'll get an object with all named exports and the `default`, i've updated my answer with unpacking that default.